# How to show textboxes side by side in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am newbie to bootstrap. How can I display a form where the textboxes should display side by side using Bootstrap?

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label >First name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Last Name</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="lastName" >
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Expected result should come as below
[image]

Comment: Different types of forms http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="firstname">First Name</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname"  
      placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last 
    Name">
  </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the other simple way you can use...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="one">One : </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="one" name="one">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="two" >Two : </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="two">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```